# Segmentation fault occurs when PyRun_SimpleFile is called repeatedly

Tags: c++, python-3.x, embedding

I want to embed a python code written in version 3.5 in c++. Also, the python script needs to be executed as the whole script repeatedly. My code as follows. It executes well for the first iteration and gives a segmentation fault at the second iteration.

main.cpp:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i<3){
    cout<<"start"<<endl;
    Py_Initialize();
    FILE* file;
    wchar_t* _argv[argc];
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++){
        wchar_t *arg = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[i], NULL);
        _argv[i] = arg;
    }

    PySys_SetArgv(argc, _argv);
    PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");

    PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("."));
    file = fopen("./example.py","r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "./example.py");
    fclose(file);
    Py_Finalize();
    cout<<"Done"<<endl;
    i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf

flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 'initial learning rate')

def main(argv=None):
    print(FLAGS.learning_rate)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I build the project using:
`cmake --build . --target Demo -- -j 2`
and executed as:
`./Demo --learning_rate 0.02`

The output was:

```
start
0.02
Done
start
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then I replaced the content of "example.py" as:
`print("Hi")`

The output was:

```
start
Hi
Done
start
Hi
Done
start
Hi
Done
```

How can I fix the above mentioned segmentation fault ?

Comment: You're leaking memory. Although not the cause of the seg fault

Comment: Initializing and finalizing the python interpreter is not required to be done each iteration

Comment: If I take initialization and finalization outside the loop, I get the following error: absl.flags._exceptions.DuplicateFlagError: The flag 'learning_rate' is defined twice. First from ./Demo, Second from ./Demo.  Description from first occurrence: initial learning rate

Comment: You should also use `Py_SetPath` before calling `Py_Initialize` in stead of importing `sys` and changing `path`. That is the correct way to do it (as long as it isn't required to change during run-time). Anyway it is hard to tell what is going wrong, since you don't really have any error checking whatsoever. Like anything could return a nullptr

Comment: Yes, because the file is already loaded then. You should wrap stuff in a function or something and call that multiple times. Re-initializing and shutting the python interpreter down is pretty expensive to do.

Comment: Since I wanted to set some flags on the python code, I followed this python script execution. Is there a way to set flags by wrapping up the stuff in a single function

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize)

> Some extensions may not work properly if their initialization routine is called more than once; this can happen if an application calls Py_Initialize() and Py_Finalize() more than once.

Comment: That could be true for TensorFlow, although the program never reaches the 'Done' output, which suggests it can't even do a single iteration.

Comment: try changing the `cout` to a `cerr`.

Comment: @Nejwiert It outputs "Done" for the first iteration